# Why does the browser show that the product category pages on my website is not secure when the website has SSL installed?

Tags: ssl, woocommerce, product, categories

At all the product category pages of my website, the browser shows that the website is unsecured. How to resolve this?

URL : https://fellowes.com.sg

Comment: I already had that problem before. Check that your template files or resources inside them, are not being called by an insecure connection.

Answer (score 0):

All of your navigation links have the `http` URL instead of `https` so when a user clicks they are directed to the `http` unsecure version.

Example from page source

```html
<li id="menu-item-2665" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2665 nav-item">
    <a href="http://fellowes.com.sg/lx-series-shredders-2/" class="nav-link">Next-Generation Shredders</a>
</li>
```

Change the links to `https://` or redirct users to `https` if they access the `http` version.